# noIndex, noFollow and Canonical Tags on Facet Page SEO

Tags: canonical-link, nofollow, noindex

We realized that we have a large number of duplicate pages of our eCommerce site indexed in Google especially the large number of facet urls such as color pages, Price pages etc.

These are already indexed each having a canonical url pointing to itself and hence.

i.e each of the facet pages such as the Black iPhone Page sub-category (facet) has the following url in the canonical tag

`http://www.example.com/category.php?item=color&item=black” />`

This is basically an exact duplicate subset.

Now we want to change that.

If they were not indexed, we could have simply had a canonical tag implementation on the Black iPhone Page pointing back to the the phones page.

So our Black iPhone page could have had the following url in the canonical tag;

`http://www.example.com/category.php?item=iphone” />`

In Addition to changing it to the new canonical tag should I also implement **Meta noindex, nofollow** on each of the facet urls to remove them from Google as we don't want them to be removed from being indexed.

Please help!

Comment: If you have duplicate content use cannonical tag to point to the 'right one'. Use Google Webmaster tools to remove the 'incorrect' urls from the Google index. I wouldn't use nofollow because it tells Google you do not trust the content which is silly if it is your own content (few exceptions exists, but IMO they're better handled by cannonical). Set up robots.txt to block / noindex sections.

Comment: So. The best thing to do in your opinion is to canonicalize the facet pages to the respective category pages. Will that remove the duplicate facet pages that are already indexed. Or do I need to noindex, nofollow each of the facet pages even after adding the canonical tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use exact page name in the pageurl, replace it with the query parameter, update website content as well. It will prevent your website from being penalized.

After doing this, setup robots.txt file using Google webmaster Tools to index or do not index website pages in Google. For more information reach us at [SEO Company in Chandigarh](http://www.veritasinfosolutions.com/best-seo-company-in-chandigarh)

Answer (score 0):

"If I was tackling this problem I would stay clear of Nofollow links because it is telling google not to trust it, which can come back to bite you later. And frankly, I hate the idea of having to nofollow my own content, it is something I often reserve for spammy links and other malicious content that annoys me. That being said, I would definitely be using a robots.txt in order to no index the areas so that you avoid penalties. It is a far more passive method that will avoid repercussion later on. The advantage of not using Nofollow with Noindex is that Pagerank can flow through the Noindex and continue on to the pages which are linked to. 
If you want some more specific advice on how to set up the robots.txt for this, feel free to contact me. 
Best of luck. 
"